# IPaddress in bytes

Tags: ipv4, poco-libraries

I have this:

```
    Poco::Net::IPAddress RequestingIP = request.clientAddress().host();
    std::cout << RequestingIP.toString();
```

but how can I read the native IPV4 address in its native Hex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IPAddress::addr()` will give you the underlying structure, eg. (this is for windows, look at your platform for details on what `in_addr` and accompanying defines look like):

```
IPAddress ia("127.0.0.1");
const in_addr* inaddr = reinterpret_cast<const in_addr*>(ia.addr());
std::cout << std::hex << inaddr->s_addr;
```